# Showing that T is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F = \mathbb{R}, V = \mathbb{R}^2$ under usual addition and scalar multiplication, and let $W = \mathbb{R}^2$ under the unusual addition:

$u \oplus v = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 + v_1 + 3 \\ u_2+v_2-2\end{bmatrix}$

$c * u = \begin{bmatrix} cu_1 + 3c - 3 \\ cu_2 - 2c + 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Consider the function $T: V \longrightarrow W$ such that $T\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4a-3 \\ 6b+2 \end{bmatrix}$

Show that $T$ is a linear transformation

Workings:

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$

$u = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix}, v = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}$

$T(u+v) = T\left( \begin{bmatrix} u_1+v_1+3 \\ u_2+v_2-2 \end{bmatrix}\right )$

$ = \begin{bmatrix} 4u_1 + 4v_1 - 6 \\ 6u_2 + 6v_2 + 4 \end{bmatrix}$

$T(u) + T(v) = \begin{bmatrix} 4u_1-3 \\ 6u_2+2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 4v_1-3 \\ 6v_2 +2 \end{bmatrix}$

$ = \begin{bmatrix} 4u_1 + 4v_1 - 6 \\ 6u_2 + 6v_2 + 4 \end{bmatrix}$

So $T(u+v) = T(u)+T(v)$

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$

$cT(u) = c \begin{bmatrix} 4u_1-3 \\ 6u_2+2 \end{bmatrix}$

$= \begin{bmatrix}4cu_1-3 \\ 6cu_2+2 \end{bmatrix}$

$=T(cu)$

I'm not sure if what I did was correct. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think $u$ and $v$ should be added normally, as they belong to $V$, not to $W$.

Comment: Oh so should it be like $T(u+v) = T(u) \oplus T(v)$?

Comment: Of course $T$ only "sees" $V$. The $\oplus$ operation is not defined on $V$.

Comment: So then $T(u+v) = \begin{bmatrix} 4u_1+4v_1+3 \\ 6u_2 + 6v_2 - 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, the unusual addition acts only on the images.

Comment: @dafinguzman Thanks. Did I do scalar multiplication correctly then? It feels like I made a similar mistake.

Comment: You had to use your special multiplication rule on each component.

Comment: @dafinguzman Thanks for the help.